# Engine run configuration was invalid

Tags: flutter

The flutter APP stays on the startup page.

IOS online installation stays on the startup page.

Error:

```
14:00:06 Hui-teki-iPhone Runner →  <Warning>: Failed to find snapshot: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F947DB6-005F-4E6D-ACEB-96E82F201FCC/Runner.app/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
14:00:07 Hui-teki-iPhone Runner →  <Warning>: 沙盒目录 = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8E7D0844-BDDC-499A-A885-5E4A0AFBF6F1/Documents
14:00:07 Hui-teki-iPhone Runner →  <Alert>: [VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(112)] Engine run configuration was invalid.
14:00:07 Hui-teki-iPhone Runner →  <Alert>: [VERBOSE-2:FlutterEngine.mm(261)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

A flutter application, the computer installation is fine, the online installation stays on the startup page.

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: Tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Is this for a debug build or an app installed using `flutter install`?

Comment: This is the application installed using flutter.

Comment: Installed how? .

Comment: Package the installation with xcode and stay on the startup page. Direct xcode installation is ok.

Comment: Try running `flutter build ios --release` and then install from xcode again.

Comment: You are right, but now I mainly add certificates to iOS package and install it on the startup page

Comment: Does that mean this solved your problem?

Comment: Basically the app get stuck on the launch screen (just in iOS)

Comment: We tried everything. It didn't work.Basically the app get stuck on the launch screen (just in iOS)

Comment: "You are right," what was I right about then?

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good, I mean I tried that, but it's not good at my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24887 suggests the same. I haven't found anything else that might be similar to your case.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me have a look.

Comment: I had the same problem after running `flutter build ios`, and `flutter clean` did not help. However, it worked again after opening the Xcode project and building to simulator, after that the error was gone.

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem when I was back to stable channel that used an old engine respect to master channel.

Try to use master channel:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Life saver bro!! Thanks you so much! +1 wasted my whole night cos it all started after I integrated firebase + facebook login sdk.. and i was trying to figure out where the hell did things go wrong! and the solution was simple enough! Thanks for posting!

Comment: Well, switching to master channel should not be part of solution. Master channel is unstable and contains new features.. Always use stable channel if you are working on realtime project

Answer (score 1):

flutter build ios/android --release/--debug  choice what you need

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vs code insiders version it worked for me after updating the flutter plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Simply solved by fixing my main.dart code. I was making some testing and accidentally commented `void main() {}` function. So before trying anything you might want to make sure main.dart code is properly wrote.